# h1 & p1 wont display inline

Tags: html, css, html-heading

I've been searching for a while now to why my heading and paragraph will not display inline.

I have tried putting them in a div to display inline.

I have also tried without the div.

here is a screen shot of what the website looks like right now 
https://gyazo.com/0331b7b59823674705305ff3e8dabd5d

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header" id="header">
    <h1>Liam Winterbourne</h1>
    <h2>Graphics Designer</h2>

    <p1>phone number</p1>
    <br></br>
    <p1>director@liaamb.co.uk</p1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
head {
}

body {
  font-family: "calibri light";
  background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
}

br {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header {
  display: inline;
}

.header h1, .header p1 {
  display: inline;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

p1 {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you create your own elements instead of using classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this structure with flex. No need of float. Change your html to like this. See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d1f21yz/1/)

```
<div class="header" id="header">
   <div style="display: flex;">
     <h1>Liam Winterbourne</h1>
     <p style="margin-left: auto;">director@liaamb.co.uk</p>
   </div>

   <div style="display: flex;">
     <h2>Graphics Designer</h2>
     <p style="margin-left: auto;">phone number</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: "calibri light";
  background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
}

.header {
  display: inline;
}


h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

p {
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look more into flex so I dont have this problem again.

Comment: there is still no p1 tag in html :)

Answer (score 0):

### Place your html like below

```
<div class="header" id="header">
    <div class="right">
    <p1>phone number</p1>
    <br></br>
    <p1>director@liaamb.co.uk</p1>
    </div>

    <h1>Liam Winterbourne</h1>
    <h2>Graphics Designer</h2>  

</div>
```

### Remove float right from p1

### Add new css like below

```
.right{
    float: right;
}
```

Just assume you have a two boxes in header like below image
[image]

If you move first box to right side then bottom box shift to the top side because of empty area, so that both boxes display in same line.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, i want to understand what the problem was here. Was it because the heading came first? I've read that they work like blocks and take up the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

flex is a good option to use it, should be trying it out. 
'p1' is not a html tag, you can use 'p'  tag.

You can try fixing this.. In your code by giving (width 50% for each element, float:left, text-align:right for right elements) to the elements this issue may be fixed.